# Usage of `program_name` in `OptionParse`

Tags: ruby

I wanted to give `OptionParse` a try. I am confused with how to use `program_name=`. From the docs:

> `program_name[W]`:
>   Program name to be emitted in error message and default banner, defaults to `$0`.

I thought I could use it like this:

```
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.program_name = 'xxxx'
  opts.on('-i', '--int N', OptionParser::DecimalInteger,
      '....'
  ) { |v| ... }
```

I expected that, if I incorrectly invoke the program with the `-i` option without an integral number, I would see an error message reporting `xxxx` as the program name. This is however not the case. Did I use `program_name=` in a wrong way, or did I misunderstand the purpose of this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the `set_program_name` method (see [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html)). The program_name member is used to retrieve the current name and set to `$0` by default. The corrected code also using `program_name` to set the banner would be:

```
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.set_program_name('xxxx')
  opts.banner = "Usage: #{opts.program_name} .."
  opts.on('-i', '--int N', OptionParser::DecimalInteger,
      '....'
  ) { |v| ... }
```